# Android - MainActivity keeps on instantiating

Tags: android, leadbolt

Im very new to android development so please bear my ignorance.

I created a Splash screen before loading my main activity. Splash is working fine but what causes the problem is the main activity, it keeps on instantiating.

**`Splash.java`**

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    final AdController optinController = new AdController(
            getApplicationContext(), "SECTION_ID");

    final Splash splash = this;

    optinController.loadOptin((Activity) splash, "SECTION_ID",
        new AdOptinListener() {
            public void onAdOptin() {
                // once optin process is complete, continue to main app activity
                launchMain();
            }
        }
    );


}

public void launchMain() {
    finish();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
}
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private AdController myController;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myController = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "SECTION_ID");
    myController.loadNotification();
}
}
```

In the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I used `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` but still it keeps on reinstantiating.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do u mean by instantiating?

Comment: @Adam It restarts the main activity endlessly.

Comment: What do you mean by it restarts the main activity endlessly? Does it keep creating multiple instances of the activity? If it does, you have to find the core cause and address it, marking it singleInstance is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

public class Splash extends Activity{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//|Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    final Timer time = new Timer();
    time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override    
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    },1000);
}}
```

It will work , i din get you exactly by instatiating.Also do no use single instance,you are not supposed to require it here.

Comment: You mean I have to remove android:launchMode="singleInstance" in my manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, following is my snippet of manifest file , just use a timer for your splash screen and move to your main class after specific time.

activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:label="@string/app_name">

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to remove the intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 0):

In manifest.xml, set category as LAUNCHER which activity you want to launch first and to Other set as DEFAULT as given in below example.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```